# How to Create Multiple Dropdown in same view controller Ios Objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in Objective-c . I don't know how to create Multiple Dropdown for ex There are Two DropDown 
1) For Country - it Contains India, China ,Usa
2) For Language - it Contains Hindi, Chineses, English.
 If User Press Country Dropdown than Language Dropdown close and vice a versa.
If User Press Outside the Dropdown than if Dropdown is open than we should closed the Dropdown .

I did't Found Any Library for Multiple Dropdown Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

Is the control you need UIPicker?
One section for country and another is language.
You code the UIPickerDelegate to realize that "If User Press Country Dropdown than Language Dropdown close and vice a versa. If User Press Outside the Dropdown than if Dropdown is open than we should closed the Dropdown ."